# How to fix the table header and row values in one table after searching inside of the php tag?

Tags: php

I created search function. After searching the results it displayed to another page and it was succeed. I had a 2 results and displayed to table. The problem is those 2 results were displayed into two tables. I want to make it as 1 table and inside of that table is the result (s).

These are the codes.

```
<?php

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do 
following
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
echo "<div id= 'table_wrapper'>";
echo "<table border='1' style='border: 1px solid  black;'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th> ID: </th>";
...
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$results['id']."</td>";
...
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";}}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
echo "No results";}}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;}
?>
```

Comment: Simple, take the table "out" of the loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be using this code in a live environment, if you are. It's totally unsafe. `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't that good neither nor safe, really.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i take out the table, there will be no table at all

Comment: why wouldn't there be?

Comment: Live means "online now" and viewable by the world.

Comment: because its for creating a table. how can i displayed the values if there is no table tag in my code? - @Fred-ii-

Comment: Place the `<table>` and `</table>` tags outside of the loop. I didn't say "remove them altogether" ;-)

Comment: welcome. There's no "debugging" to be done, since the code "works". Someone gave you an answer below to which I easily could have done. Why I didn't do that is simple: I wanted *you* to do it and *learn* ;-) that's what I like to do, is teach people "how to fish", rather than simply "throwing them a fish" ;-)

Comment: where will i put that table tags? - @Fred-ii-

Comment: i tried, but it doesnt work. I tried to remove the table tag from the loop, but i got the same result - @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Saffron please check answer.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer, its still the same, it only change their position, but its still the same, I still got two headers and two rows.

Comment: thanks for the help. I got it. thanks to @Fred-ii-. I just realized that you were right. What a great help for my simple question that I thought it was hard to fix. I was just analyzed what you have said to me a while ago.

Comment: you're welcome @Saffron *cheers!*

Comment: By the way @Saffron Stack lets you post your own answer with the solution you came up with. You can then accept your own answer when Stack lets you. I'd be glad to upvote it, just let me know if and when you do.

Comment: ok wait a minute - @Fred-ii-

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<th> ID: </th>
<th> Firstname: </th>
<th> Last name: </th>
<th> Job title: </th>
<th> Department: </th>
<th> Email address: </th>
<th> Contact number: </th>
<th> Company Name: </th>
</tr>
<?php
//insert php code here

Comment: im sorry the above comment is a mistake. ill try to post the code later - @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY GOT THE ANSWER!

```
**NOTE: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:** *And its totally working as I 
wanted.*
<table>
<tr>
<th> ID: </th>
...
</tr>

<?php
//other php code here ...
<?php
//other php code here ...
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$results['id']."</td>";
...
echo "</tr>";}}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
echo "No results";}}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;}  
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this.
 Take table out of your loop.

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    $min_length = "";
    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tqA
    WHERE (`date_now` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`first_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')  OR (`last_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')  OR (`job_title` LIKE '%".$query."%')  OR (`department` LIKE '%".$query."%')  OR (`company_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
    echo "<div id= 'table_wrapper'>";
    echo "<table border='1' style='border: 1px solid  black;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> ID: </th>";
    echo "<th> Firstname: </th>";
    echo "<th> Last name: </th>";
    echo "<th> Job title: </th>";
    echo "<th> Department: </th>";
    echo "<th> Email address: </th>";
    echo "<th> Contact number: </th>";
    echo "<th> Company Name: </th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$results['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$results['date_now']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['first_name']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['last_name']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['department']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['email_address']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['phone_cell']."</td> ";
    echo "<td>" .$results['company_name']."</td> ";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    echo "No results";}}
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;}
    ?>
```